# How do I ignore click events and allow selection with React?

Tags: reactjs, dom-events

In my React component I have a click event handler on the component's root element. I need to prevent this event bubbling when the user clicks a certain child element *but also* allow the double click to highlight the inner text as it would do usually.

I have tried to attach a click handler to the child element and call `event.stopPropagation()` which does prevent the parent click handler from firing but doing a double-click does not highlight the text.

Is there a way to do this?

Footnote: After writing this question I wonder if the only way is to use `createTextRange()`

Comment: I think we need to know more about your double-click handler. If you could provide the code for the component that would be best.

Comment: There is no double-click handler. I meant the default thing that happens when you double-click any browser text.

Comment: Can you provide the component code?